# Debian Jessie bind9 permission problem

Tags: debian, bind

Whenever I start bind9 (/etc/init.d/bind9 start) I get the following reply:

```
[FAIL] Starting domain name service...: bind9 failed
```

This is what /var/log/syslog gives me:

```
... named[28282]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
... named[28282]: open: /etc/bind/named.conf: permission denied
```

All files in /etc/bind/* are owned by root and grouped as bind and permissions are 644 for all.

/etc/default/bind9 :

```
OPTIONS="-u bind"
```

Systemd is purged from the system.

I have tried changing permissions and owners to no avail.

This is the first time this has happened to me.

Comment: What are the rights and ownership of `/etc/bind`?

Comment: /etc/bind: drwxr-sr-x root bind

Comment: What you can do is change the rights of the file to 777 and see if it starts. If so then verify if it is really bind that runs named. Change it back to 644 afterwards.

Comment: I changed it to 777 ... same problem ...

Comment: Is `named` being chroot'ed? The default `chroot` for `named` on FreeBSD is `/var/named`; so the actual path to the config file is `/var/named/etc/namedb/named.conf` but it's specified in the rc var as `/etc/namedb/named.conf`.

Comment: I bit the bullet and did a clean install ... :( ... think it's time for me to leave Debian and it's politics behind ... opt for some other *nix ... thanks for trying to help guys ...